# Why is socket.io giving me a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am basically trying to recreate a simple chat application posted on the official website of socket.io.

I created the following module in content.js:

```
var app = require('express');
var router  = app.Router();

    module.exports = function(app, io) {

        app.get('/profile',function(req, res){
            res.render('profile.ejs');
        });
        io.on('connection', function(socket){
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
                io.emit('chat message', msg);
            });
        });
        return router;
    };
```

I am calling it from index.js through this:

```
// socket.io
var server   = require('http').Server(app);
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);
require('./app/content')(app, io);
```

while running the app, nothing is being sent and the following error(s) are displayed in my console:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1461512892706-14 404 2.370 ms - 1097
```

How can I fix this? as far as i read it got something to do with the location of profile.ejs? Thank you as always for any help

Here is index.js:

```
var express         = require('express')
var path            = require('path');
var favicon         = require('serve-favicon');
var logger          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var passport        = require('passport');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');
var session         = require('express-session');
var routes          = require('./routes/index');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var users           = require('./routes/users');
var home            = require('./routes/home');
var mysql           = require('mysql');
var helmet          = require('helmet');
var app             = express();


// socket.io
var server   = require('http').Server(app);
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);


require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console


app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'mysql',
    database: 'clearreview'
});
connection.connect();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// security measure against xss attacks
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
// hide powered by express
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
// security measure against sniffing
app.use(helmet.noSniff());


app.use('/', routes);



// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'vidyapathaisalwaysrunning',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


// routes ======================================================================
//require('./app/cr-auth-routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
require('./app/cr-auth-routes')(app, passport);
require('./app/search.js')(app, connection);
require('./app/content')(app, io);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

www file that launches the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('clear-review:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Please show us to rest of `index.js`.  We need to see how you define `app` and how you start your server.  Also, get rid of the `router` and `app` variables in `content.js` as you aren't using them and they are just a point of possible confusion.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for replying, i updated my answer to post index.js

Comment: I don't see where you're actually starting your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am starting my server in a www file. I posted it now

Comment: just look at http://socket.io/docs/, see the express 3/4 example, and see where your code takes a wrong turn?

Comment: The `www` file seems to create a different server and start that one.  You need to have only one server created and start the one in `index.js` that socket.io is hooked to.  It appears you are never starting the actual server created in `index.js` that socket.io is hooked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are creating two separate servers, one in your `www` file with:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

And, another one in `index.js` with:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
```

You are never starting the one created in `index.js` and that's the one that socket.io is connected to so that's why you don't have any socket.io functionality.  The server you bound socket.io to was never started.

You are starting the one your `www` file, but it has no socket.io connected to it.

You need to create one server and only one server and have that be the server that Express and socket.io are bound to.  And, then you need to start that one server.

Comment: Do you think its a better approach to update the www file or the index.js?

Comment: @Predator44 - Honestly, the module layout you've shown so far looks too complicated for me to follow what you're trying to do overall.  It looks to me like `index.js` is where the meat of setting up your server is so that's probably where you should create it and start it, but I don't feel like I have the 50,000 foot view of what you're trying to do overall or even really understand why you have the `www` file at all.

Comment: I'll just remove the www file, and try to update my index.js. www was created by the express app generator and I haven't really touched it since then.